# Difference between sigma and cov-matrix in multivariate normal GAM

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, multivariate-normal-distribution, mgcv

I'm confused about the difference between sigma and the cov-matrix when one fits a multivariate normal gam.

More precise, I used for example `mvn(d=2)` when fitting a two-dimensional normal GAM to model $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. The GAM fit is denoted by `b` in the following

From the documentation, I known that the covariance matrix of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ can be obtained via

> `covMatrix <- solve(crossprod(b$family$data$R))`

*(code is taken from the documentation of the "Multivariate normal additive models").*

What I was thinking is that $Var(Y_1) =$ `covMatrix [1,1]` and $Var(Y_2)=$ `covMatrix[2,2]` hold.

When bringing back everything introduced so far to the usual GAM formula, I would assume that
$$Y_1 = \mu_1 + Var(Y_1) * \epsilon_1, \quad \epsilon_1 \sim N(0,1). (*)$$

Is this so far correct, i.e. does $(*)$ hold?

And if so, what is `b$sig2`? I fitted various multivariate Normal GAMs and all yielded `b$sig2=1` which seems a bit strange to me since the covariance matrices varied greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sig2` is the dispersion parameter $\phi$ in the GLM context. It is set to 1 I believe so as to have no effect in this kind of model, because R has been estimated.